# Project Creation Failed in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, project

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop on my Windows 7 Ultimate(32bit) PC. I've registered it. My problem is about its Visual C++ projects. When I tried to created a VC++ project it says,

```
"Creating project '<project_name>'... project creation failed."
```

[image]

But I think Everything installed correctly and I can't find any wrong with this software. Please Help me what's the problem. I re-installed the program many times and run it with administrator, disabled UAC but nothing helped me

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a [frequent problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/0b7b9506-2ca3-4b42-be26-02796e471d26) related to UAC and administrative rights.

Comment: I disabled UAC and checked and I run VCE2012 as admin but none of these helped me

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above solutions, but the below mentioned steps helped me at last. Please try out that if none of the above solutions worked for you.

1. Go to Libraries\Documents folder
2. Right click on the folder IISExpress and click Properties
3. Go to Advanced options
4. Under Compress or Encrypt attributes, please uncheck the checkbox 'Encrypt
   contents to secure data'
5. Click Ok and apply.

Now try to create a project, hope you won't get the error again.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this [update KB2781514](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2781514)
This works for me